# solution of an SDE (textbook exercise)

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I am looking at a problem (5.1.iii, pg 93 of the pdf or pg 73 of the book: [http://th.if.uj.edu.pl/~gudowska/dydaktyka/Oksendal.pdf](http://th.if.uj.edu.pl/%7Egudowska/dydaktyka/Oksendal.pdf))

The function $X_t = \text{sin }B_t$ for any $B_0 = a \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ solves the Ito SDE $dX_t = -\frac{1}{2}X_t dt + \sqrt{1 - X_t^2}dBt$ which seems pretty clear from Ito's formula and the identity $sin^2x + cos^2 x = 1$.  But the problem stipulates that this solution is only valid for $t < \text{inf}(s > 0 | B_s \not\in[-\pi/2, \pi/2])$.

What is the reason for bounding $t$ to prevent $B_t$ escaping $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$?  If the trig functions are periodically extended, shouldn't this solution be valid for all $t$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly outside of that interval the cosine is negative, the square root would need to change its sign. Thus the given function would not solve the given SDE. It does not necessarily mean that the SDE does not have a solution, but it will no longer be the sine.

Comment: Right.  So, is $X_t = \text{sin } B_t$ a valid solution to $dX_t = -\frac{1}{2}X_tdt + cos X_t dB_t$?

Comment: No, of course not, as that would contain the composition $\cos(\sin(B_t))$. You can only break that singularity by adding the equation for $Y_t=\cos B_t$.

Comment: If you apply Ito's formula to $X_t = \text{sin} B_t$ you get $d X_t = \text{cos} B_t dB_t - \frac{1}{2}\text{sin} B_t dt$ which is $-\frac{1}{2}X_tdt + \text{cos }\text{sin}^{-1} X_t dB_t$, so the problem is with $\text{cos }\text{sin}^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$.  I get it, thanks.

Comment: I meant you get the coupled system \begin{align}dX_t&=-\tfrac12X_t\,dt+Y_t\,dB_t\\dY_t&=-\tfrac12Y_t\,dt-X_t\,dB_t\end{align} which has no root terms.